# How to relax the rules for Jenkins Content Security policy in tomcat installation

Tags: jenkins, content-security-policy

I'm having an issue with Jenkins HTML Publisher Plugin when i click on the links inside the published HTML reports. This is due to Jenkins Content Security Policy. I want to relax the rules by configuring the below while kicking off the jenkins.war. 
**-Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP**
But i'm not sure where I can find this in my installation. We're using Tomcat, hence no jenkins.xml. I'm not a Jenkins expert.